# Android: Using an IntentService for rapid data

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I have an Android app that will be receiving rapid data over bluetooth (BLE).  The data will be arriving at 50-100 Hz from a remote sensor device into a dedicated service (the Nordic nRF BLE manager) on an Android smartphone.  I want to hand the data, at full rate, to a separate service to compute analytics on it.  If I use an IntentService for the analytics, that means intents will come in every 10 milliseconds.  I'm sure there is significant overhead for each Intent and I doubt it was designed for this much data.  But everything I read suggests that this is the simplest solution.  Is this the right approach?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the sensor data is from a remote device and *not* from the sensors on the Android phone.  Just wanted to clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to decide whether you need real-time behavior. The data is being received over BLE in real-time, but do you really need to process it in real time? If the analytics that you're computing are not required in real-time, then it is ok to receive the data, store it, and process later.

If you really need real-time data processing then `IntentService` is not an adequate design choice.

If you don't need real-time data processing then `IntentService` can work, but will be non-optimal from performance point of view.

There will be two overheads.

The first one you found by yourself - sending intent bears some additional overhead because the OS needs to "route" the intent to the service.

The second one will be associated with starting and stopping the `IntentService`. If the period of time between intent arrivals will be lower than the time it takes `onHandleIntent()` to return, then the system will be starting and stopping the `IntentService` for each intent. This overhead is much higher that the first one.

Therefore, even though `IntentService` can work in this situation, IMHO you shouldn't use this approach.

The best solution to this problem will be to use bound `Service`. Bind to it from the BLE receiver and send the data using regular method calls. The downside is that you'll need to implement two features by yourself:

1. Blocking queue for data that needs to be processed
2. The logic that offloads the processing to background thread

Writing this logic is not trivial, but if your application is a serious project, then it is the only right thing to do IMHO. You can copy-paste threading logic from the source code of `IntentService`.

**One word of caution**: you must be aware of excessive memory consumption. For example: if you use a single background thread for processing, and the rate of incoming data is higher than the rate of processing, then your queue will be constantly growing. In such a situation, if given enough time, your application will crash with OutOfMemory exception (can happen with `IntentService` too).

If this happens, you'll need to do either of:

1. Use multiple threads for background processing
2. Store data into SQLite (but then SQLite can grow excessively)
3. Drop some data

Comment: There is a HandlerThread, which has Looper with a queue of Messages and do all the work in background

Comment: Great answer.  I was thinking of using a Bound Service, but had not considered the issues of a queuing.  The work is not realtime.  The samples will be fast, but the analytics are computed ever second or so.  However, I cant drop samples.

Comment: As I think about this then, the point is to write the data into the buffer as quickly as possible (with little overhead) and then fork off the analytics into a separate thread to ensure that the main UI thread does not back up and drop samples.

Comment: @AlexShutov, yes, using `HandlerThread` could be one possible and easy solution for both features.

Comment: @Hephaestus, sounds like a good plan. However, there is one complication that you should be aware of when using single thread for processing. I added additional info at the end of the answer.

Comment: Just finished the implementation.  I can confirm that service-to-service communication using a LocalBinder interface and direct calls is simple and easy.  I now have both the UI Activity and the BLE Service communicating directly with the analytics Service.  I followed the instructions here and had it up in 1-2 hours.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IntentService has embedded queue of incoming Intents, so, if you process intents slower than they arrive, it is possible to do. 
But, I'd use HandlerThread for posting incoming data within Message onto it. It has embedded message queue too, but there is no overhead, as with  creating IntentService. 
Another approach - use ordinary Service and handle backpressure with RxJava library.

Comment: I'm also considering using a Bound Service with a LocalBinder.  This would allow BLE Service to make a direct call into the Analytics Service to put the data in place.  I'll also look into a HandlerThread.